# Android application theme error:style Optional.of(AAPT)

Tags: android

[image]

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details

Comment: You need to share your `style.xml` as **`TEXT`**

Comment: Update to the newest Android Studio, this bug was fixed already.